# Disable integrated windows security while browsing on localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integrated-security

I am developing an intranet MVC3 application that will be used by both domain and non domain computers.
Everyone has a domain account so whenever a non domain computer is to open the website a windows credentials prompt input box is expected to appear.

If i understand correctly this will be standard browser behavior since they won't pass windows credentials to a website unless they are in the same domain.

The problem however is that whenever i debug on my localhost i am in the same domain as the server(since i am the server obviously). This results in me being "logged in" with my workgroup windows account in stead of my domain account.
What i'm looking for is a way to trigger the prompt box so i can use my domain account to login rather then to get useless access with my workgroup account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Forms authentication with the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx).

Take a look to this tutorial on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx and this post: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340/en-us (sorry it's VB code).

**Addendum**: if you want just to test another user credentials you can use impersonation, just set-up your web.config.

Comment: If i switch to forms authenication users will have to log in everytime or i'd have to create an auto logon if they are in the domain. That seems like a lot of hassle for something that should be working out of the box. I do like the sound of impersonating another user but i thought impersionation only switched the user that is running the application pool, not the actual user that is browsing the website.

Comment: Yes, it's a little bit boring. I _guess_ it can be done inside authentication classes created by project template for testing purposes but it's annoying. I added another link in the answer.